# Dapper function doesn't map the string values from stored procedure, but maps the other values correctly

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, dapper

I have a stored procedure which returns data in the following format:

```
"CompanyId"|"MetadataId"|"Mnemonic"|"Short"|"format"|"MetaDataType"|"lngValue"|"decValue"|"charValue"|"dateValue"|"blnValue"|"sOrder"|"version"|"Type"|"SortOrder"|"createdDate"
```

The only strings are `Mnenomic` and `Short`. The SP also returns multiple rows which is why I was thinking that using a `IEnumerable<MyClass>` would be the best way to map the rows.

My class for mapping the data:

```
public class CreditDataReport
    {
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public int MetaDataId { get; set; }
        public string Mnenomic { get; set; }
        public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
        public int format { get; set; }
        public int MetaDataType { get; set; }
        public int lngValue { get; set; }
        public double decValue { get; set; }
        public string charValue { get; set; }
        public DateTime dateValue { get; set; }
        public int? blnValue { get; set; }
        public int SOrder { get; set; }
        public int version { get; set; }
        public int Type { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
        public DateTime createdDate { get; set; }
    }
```

And the method for calling my SP and mapping the data:

```
public IEnumerable<CreditDataReport> GetCreditRecommendation(int reportId)
        {
            dynamic result = connection.Query<CreditDataReport>("cor_CreditRatioDataXXGetByReportId", new { ReportId = reportId },
                transaction: this.transaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            return result;
        }
```

My problem is that when I call the function like this `var testing = GetCreditRecommendation(2).ToList();` and I walk through my code at runtime I see that all the data is correctly mapped to their corresponding value in the `CreditReportData`class except for the two string values `Mnenomic`and `Short`.

What am I missing in my code and am I using dapper in the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mnemonic` != `Mnenomic` (look very very carefully)

`Short` != `ShortDesc`

Comment: Thank you!

I was staring myself blind on this. Embarrassed about how easy it is for me to miss something like that.

Comment: @Gurkmeja101 no problem; I was reminded of: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EbQ-0SX8ikM